# gson parsing of a unknown type attribute android

Tags: android, json, gson

in my application i need to parse a class.. i am using gson for parsing. the sturcture is

```
public class Showcase implements Serializable{

public String xxx_url;
public String image_url;
public String _source;}
```

the json structure is: `

```
[{
_source: {
FlyerID: "infly7",
category: "Electronics and home appliances",
image_url: "xxx.jpg",
issuer: "elica",
issuer_type: "brand",
original_image_url: "yyy.jpg",
thumbnail_image_url: "xxx_yyy.jpg",
valid_from: "2014-12-06",
valid_until: "2015-01-06"
},
image_url: "ccc.jpg",
xxx_url: "ddd"
}
{
_source: {
BOGO: null,
cashback: null,
category: "Mobiles and tablets",
color_code: "cbbdca",
discount_percentage: null,
discount_type: null,
fp_type: null,
image_url: "xxx.jpg",
issuer: "JBL",
product_classification: [
"Speaker"
],
title: "JBL Bt Speaker"
},
image_url: "xxx.jpg",
xxx_url: "eeee"
}]`
```

i don't know the structure of _source so i want to store it as string.how to store the_source json object as a string using gson

Answer (score 0):

What does "i don't know the structure of _source" mean? You have the structure of source. It's an object so you have to create another class in which you will define _source properties and you will access to it in your Showcase class:

**Source.class**

```
public class Source {
    String FlyerID;
    String category;
    String image_url;
    String issuer;

    // do also the other properties

    public Source (String FlyerID, String category){  //do the same for the other properties
        this.FlyerID = FlyerID;
        this.category = category;
        //other assignment
    }
}
```

**Showcase.class**

```
public class Showcase{
    Source _source;
    String image_url;
    String xxx_url;
}
```

Now i have seen better your json source so as i wrote in the comments, i recommend to change the json resource (if you can) because different attributes everytime take to an awful parsing. 
In case you can't you can use all variables in source class that will be set to null if the attribute isn't used:

```
public class Source {
    String FlyerID;
    String BOGO;
    String category;
    String cashback;
    String image_url;
    String color_code;
    String issuer;

    // do also the other properties

    public Source (String FlyerID, String category){  //do the same for the other properties
        this.FlyerID = FlyerID;
        this.category = category;
        //other assignment
    }
}
```

But as the third time, this isn't the right way. Because if you say that attributes change everytime, maybe in future a new attribute can appear in the json file and its parsing will stop at that line.

Comment: the _source attributes are changing for each requests

Comment: @user1992200 : "the _source attributes are changing for each requests" : In that case it's an extremely poor OO design.

Comment: @user1992200 can't you ask to who implemented this json structure to use everytime all the same attributes and set them to null when they aren't used? Because the gson library also permits to parse an incomplete object for example you can parse also an object that hasn't the category attribute. But you can't parse a json that has more attributes than those in the class. I recommend you to change the json structure or create a class with ALL attributes, so in the case they aren't in the received object they will be automatically set to null by gson library.

Comment: @Fondesa yeah.. dynamically changing attributes will cause problems.. in my app xxx_url is the key used to get the  _source objects type..so instead of parsing the _source jsonobject i am storing it as a string...afetr getting the xxx_url type parsing the _source using appropriate model class